# How to write function where callback can be at more than one argument position in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

This is what I have so far, but an error is thrown for `bar[key]` (see [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwDCBDANmgRigxgaygF4oAKASiID4oA3AewEsATAKBYYDtgIAnAM1zQAQih5QA3iyhQA2ngggAXFEQ9OAcwC6y1RpYBfNjjodEUbmeJ8ArhxzAGJklKh86dHcDUd1AGhfYPAD8yiJiAD6wCMjoWLh4-tI4sdj4IVGIqBipeCwUktIMfKSgkHTFgUSExABENnYOJjX5Lkkp8URQga1dop22TBB8nBCs0oaFxSSVAGQzvWKciCh2EOVQAPKYAFYQ9i3S0lu79gB08iDw06Jkp248AKK4ABYk9faOHCQXB4dJJvA6GgIKc0HR1N8FL4FnIFJoyD19Ajxi4iqRktl4r82pj8OQXIZ9EA)).

I would like to be able to call `test` using `test("hello", { foo: "bar" }, () => {})` and `test("hello", () => {})`.

```js
type TestCallback = () => void

interface Bar {
  [key: string]: string
}

const test = function(
  foo: string,
  bar?: Bar | TestCallback | null,
  callback?: TestCallback
) {
  if (typeof bar === "function") {
    callback = bar
    bar = null
  }
  if (bar && bar instanceof Object) {
    Object.keys(bar).forEach(function(key) {
      console.log(key, bar[key])
    })
  }
  if (callback) {
    callback()
  }
}
```

Comment: You *could*  probably do it by linking the parameters in some fashion, but I'd actually ask - why not pass in a parameter object? It seems a lot easier for 1. typing 2. consuming 3. calling. It would reduce the complexity of using that function all around.

Comment: @VLAZ Great feedback. I’m refactoring legacy code so I need to follow that argument layout.

Comment: This one seem to work. I am not sure if this is what you wanted.

`const test = function(
  foo: string,
  bar?: Bar | TestCallback,
  callback?: TestCallback
) {
  if (typeof bar === "function") {
    console.log('bar is a function');
    bar();
  } else if (bar instanceof Object) {
    Object.keys(bar).forEach(function(key) {
      console.log(key, bar[key])
    })
    if (callback) {
      callback();
    }
  }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a weird decision by the TypeScript compiler.

1. `bar` is **not** immutable, so it can change
2. You have `bar[key]` defined in a *different function* (the callback to `.forEach`)

The compiler seems to believe that because of that, `bar` *might* have changed by the time the function executes.

This is incorrect - the function is defined and used synchronously, so there is no chance of `bar` being reassigned between the definition and invocation.

Still, the compiler complains.

Here are some ways to avoid it

## Type assertion (not recommended)

Just overrule the compiler:

```
if (bar && bar instanceof Object) {
  Object.keys(bar).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key, (bar as Bar)[key])
  })
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwDCBDANmgRigxgaygF4oAKASiID4oA3AewEsATAKBYYDtgIAnAM1zQAQih5QA3iyhQA2ngggAXFEQ9OAcwC6y1RpYBfNjjodEUbmeJ8ArhxzAGJklKh86dHcDUd1AGhfYPAD8yiJiAD6wCMjoWLgEkRzWGP7SOLHY+CFRiKgYmXgsFJLSDHykoJB05YFEhMQARDZ2DiYNxS5pGfFEUIGdfaK9SRguhqXlJLUAZNODYpyIKHYQ1VAA8pgAVhD2HdLSmzv2AHTyIPBTomQnbjwAorgAFiTN9o4cJOf7B2km8HQ0BATmg6OovgpfKRaih4FAwmQ5ApNGQBvpUdJxlAyqR0vl4j8uvj8OQxgYgA)

It's the simplest one but it might be a problem if you change `bar`'s type to be possibly something else `bar?: Bar | Baz | TestCallback | null` and forget to update the type assertion. The compiler wouldn't complain, so it might be easy to overlook it.

## Repeat the type guard (not recommended)

```
if (bar && bar instanceof Object) {
  Object.keys(bar).forEach(function(key) {
    if (bar && bar instanceof Object) {
      console.log(key, (bar as Bar)[key])
    }
  })
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwDCBDANmgRigxgaygF4oAKASiID4oA3AewEsATAKBYYDtgIAnAM1zQAQih5QA3iyhQA2ngggAXFEQ9OAcwC6y1RpYBfNjjodEUbmeJ8ArhxzAGJklKh86dHcDUd1AGhfYPAD8yiJiAD6wCMjoWLgEkRzWGP7SOLHY+CFRiKgYmXgsFJLSDHykoJB05YFEhMQARDZ2DiYNxS5pGfFEUIGdfaK9SRguhqXlJLUAZNODYpyIKHYQ1VAA8pgAVhD2HdLSmzv2AHTyIPBTomQnbjwAorgAFiTN9o4cJOf7BxOkM3NaotgMscKtykddsAfr80iZ4HQ0BATmg6OovgpfP8hih4FAwmQ5ApNGQBtJxgd9KTyS4yqR0vl4jCoAy4vhyGMDEA)

This will also assure the compiler that `bar` is actually a `Bar` type when you get to it. However, it's a useless check because it shouldn't be needed. It makes the code harder to read and understand.

## Use `const`

```
if (bar && bar instanceof Object) {
  const baz = bar; //won't be reassigned
  Object.keys(bar).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key, baz[key]) //would still be the same
  })
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwDCBDANmgRigxgaygF4oAKASiID4oA3AewEsATAKBYYDtgIAnAM1zQAQih5QA3iyhQA2ngggAXFEQ9OAcwC6y1RpYBfNjjodEUbmeJ8ArhxzAGJklKh86dHcDUd1AGhfYPAD8yiJiAD6wCMjoWLgEkRzWGP7SOLHY+CFRiKgYmXgsFJLSDHykoJB05YFEhMQARDZ2DiYNxS5pGfFEUIGdfaK9SRguhqXlJLUAZNODYpyIKHYQ1VAA8pgAVhD2HdJpJmbYAF69gQDcUAD01wDuJgDkwH3QPBAo8PAM6hwQrAcNttdsAAHTyEDwKaiMigtw8ACiuAAFiRmvZHBwSBD9oCoMZTHQ0BBQWg6OpsQpfIMTnIFJoKLcHskmCoHBhXuZkdB4CgALYQAb6MhjFxlUjpfLxXFdKX4cii-RAA)

A `const` cannot be reassigned, so the compiler will know that `baz` can *only* be of type `Bar` after the type guards and won't change by the time the function executes.

Still adds an extra line but it's at least more sensible than direct overruling the compiler or re-assessing the type of `bar`.

## Extract the `forEach` callback and curry it

This one is an option but probably won't be of use every time.:

```
const f = (obj: Bar) => (key: keyof Bar) => {
  console.log(key, obj[key])
}

/* ... */

if (bar && bar instanceof Object) {
  Object.keys(bar).forEach(f(bar))
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwDCBDANmgRigxgaygF4oAKASiID4oA3AewEsATAKBYYDtgIAnAM1zQAQih5QA3iyhQA2ngggAXFEQ9OAcwC6y1RpYBfNjjodEUPkVJ1MAK2UieFQtRLylUN3QsOn1SdONTOjQIADo0OnVXBQAaKGsbOQVNMgMjEzNuM2I+AFcOHGAGExIpczo6HWA1DnUYsuweAH57USgAH1gEZHQsXAJOjlyMeoDe7HwWrsRUDAm8Fgp-KAYLElBILyhGokJiACI8gqKTfaWysbn+y0aL7bbiIYwyw2lV0h2AMk-7sU5EFAFCBbADytgghXO0mkYJsEOAoTc8BIjTIoT4dB4AFFcAALEh8FGiMipaSvFZrHDjfpQ6FUq74cgvAxAA)

It's *similar* to using `const` as it traps `bar` in a different variable that the compiler will not complain might change. On the other hand, it might be an overkill for this task. Yet still, it might be more useful in some situations, if you already want functions

## Use `for...of` (recommended)

This is still a way to bypass the wrong interpretation of the compiler by just eliminating the cause of it - removing the function definition:

```
if (bar && bar instanceof Object) {
  for (let key of Object.keys(bar)) {
    console.log(key, bar[key]);
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwDCBDANmgRigxgaygF4oAKASiID4oA3AewEsATAKBYYDtgIAnAM1zQAQih5QA3iyhQA2ngggAXFEQ9OAcwC6y1RpYBfNjjodEUbmeJ8ArhxzAGJklKh86dHcDUd1AGhfYPAD8yiJiAD6wCMjoWLh4-tI4sdj4IVGIqBipeCwUktIMfKSgkHTFgUSExABENnYOJjX5Lkkp8URQga1dop22TBB8nBCs0oaFxSSVAGQzvWKciCh2EOVQAPKYAFYQ9i3S0m5iJGgQwFDyIFDrW7v2AHRX8NOiZAeHSSbwdGcPaHR1CQrr4FnIFJoyABuHoTKBwoqkZLZeIfNoo-DkFyGfRAA)

Without a function definition, the compiler can *only* interpret that `bar` will not change between the checks for its type and the time it's used.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is related in the way you use `bar` function argument, by default TS treats arguments as consts, but when we change them, and you do, by setting `bar = null` then TS treats it as `let`. This difference is visible below:

```
{
  // with let function declaration has not narrowed type
  let a: string | number = 1;
  if (typeof a === 'number') {
    a // a is number yep
    const f = () => {
      a // a is not to be believed so it is string | number
    }
  }
}
{
  // with const function declaration has narrowed type
  const a: string | number = 1;
  if (typeof a === 'number') {
    a // a is number yep
    const f = () => {
      a // a is still number as it is const
    }
  }
}
```

So when we use `const` function declaration inside the type guard sees this type as narrowed, but with `let` it doesn't trust it. Why? Because for example function can be called asynchronously and the variable can change before, so TS is more defensive for `let` in order to prevent run-time bugs.

The situation applies in your case, by re-assigning argument `bar` TS is switching it to `let` mode. We can fix it by removing the the re-assignment. Consider:

```
const test = function(
  foo: string,
  bar?: Bar | TestCallback,
  callback?: TestCallback
) {
  if (bar && typeof bar !== 'function') {
    Object.keys(bar).forEach((key) => {
      console.log(key, bar[key]) // no error bar is Bar
    })
  }
  if (callback) {
    callback()
  }
}
```

**Additional thoughts**

Some thoughts about this behavior and if it is wrong or not. Its subjective, we need to understand many factors, also this one where compilation needs to be fast. TS is choosing here straight forward approach, you re-assign, TS believes less in your type guards persistence. It can be a burden in some cases like yours, but still there are a lot other cases which benefit from this safety.

Comment: Ah, I see - it's the reassignment that is tripping TS up. I didn't know about this. I suppose then the solution is simple - just declare a new variable instead of re-assigning `bar` and `callback`. After doing appropriate checks, it should be a matter of `let cb = callback; if (!cb) if (typeof bar === "function") cb = bar;` then use `cb` instead of `callback`. No reassignments needed to parameters.

Comment: You should do everythin to not re-assign and TS will be happy. Generally re-assigning or mutation arguments are not good ideas