# TypeScript union type narrowing and assignment problem

Tags: typescript, types

TypeScript can correctly narrow union type with a sample code like this:

```
interface Callable {
  call(): void
}
declare function getCallable(): Callable

let x: string | Callable = { call(){} }

if (typeof x === 'string') {
  x = getCallable()
  // `x` can only be `Callable` here
}
x.call()
```

But it didn't work on the actual code, which is similar to the code above:

```
form(obj: object | FormData): Request {
    if (!(obj instanceof FormData)) {
        const form = new FormData()
        for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(obj)) {
            form.append(k, v)
        }
        obj = form
    }
    // `obj` must be FormData here, but why `obj` is still `object | FormData`?
    const stream = new Readable()
    stream.push(obj.getBuffer()) // FormData has getBuffer() and getHeaders()
    this._body = stream
    this.header(obj.getHeaders())
    return this
}
```

I thought `!(obj instanceof FormData)` means only `object` can enter the `if` block, and `obj` get assigned to a `FormData` there, so `obj` must be `FormData`.
But TypeScript compiler complains that `obj` doesn't have `getBuffer()` and `getHeaders()`, because they are `object | FormData`, not `FormData`. Also, what should I do without directly casting like `(<FormData>obj).getBuffer()`?

Comment: you dont return in the `if` block so the code continues and TS properly shows the whole type.

Comment: @MaciejSikora But I have `obj = form`, which assigns `obj` to `FormData` type.

Comment: Yes but TS is not doing the code evaluation, so at the type level it is not even analyzed. This code doesn't effect the outside block

Comment: @MaciejSikora But in the first example, didn't TS correctly figure out that `x` can only be `Callable`?

Comment: Ok I am totally wrong :D sorry for that. Looks like `x instanceof Y` is a typeguard but `!(x instanceof Y)` is not

Comment: [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) doesn't have `getBuffer` and `getHeaders`. Are you mistaking it with something else?

Comment: @VLAZ The `FormData` here came from https://github.com/form-data/form-data , which is not totally same as browser's version.

Comment: @MaciejSikora So, maybe this is a TS compiler problem?

Comment: Ok last thought is that it is about how TS treats arguments - as consts not as let, that is why reassign is not considered. Bingo! :)

Comment: @MaciejSikora yeah, now I remember as well. It's the same as your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60661898/3689450).

Comment: Yep, the same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is related with how arguments are treated by TS. They are treated as `const` not like `let`. It means that TS doesn't follow re-assigning of arguments. Of course you can do so, as in the runtime it is possible (re-assigning const is not) but TS is in the "const mode" for arguments. The solution is temporary variable:

```
function form(obj: object | FormData): Request {
    let finalObj: FormData;
    if (!(obj instanceof FormData)) {
        const form = new FormData()
        for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(obj)) {
            form.append(k, v)
        }
        finalObj = form
    } else {
      finalObj = obj;
    }
    // rest of the code should use finalObj
```

Why TS does that - re-assigning arguments in general is not a good practice, so treating them as `const` is reasonable. Take a look at similar issue with exactly that behavior - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60661334/how-to-write-function-where-callback-can-be-at-more-than-one-argument-position-i/60661898#60661898)